# Laravel Eloquent Query error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I Have been trying to run the following controller in the Laravel 4.0 Framework. Any ideas whats wrong with my controller?:

```
public function results()
    {   
        $query = DB::table('Unions'); // Get the table before applying the where clauses

        if (Request::get('Affilation')) {
            $Affilation = input::get('Affilation');
            if ($Affilation != null) {
                $query = $query->where('Affilation', $Affilation);
            }
        }

        if (Request::get('Office_State')) {
            $Office_State = input::get('Office_State');
            if ($Office_State != null) {
                $query = $query->where('Office_State', $Office_State);
            }
        }

        if (Request::has('Local_Name')) {
            $Local_Name = input::get('Local_Name');
            if ($Local_Name != null) {
                $query = $query->where('Local_Name', $Local_Name);
            }
        }

        $results = $query->get(); // Calling get() will execute the query, so it must be last to be called
        //show results from union search
        return View::make('results')->with('union', $results);
     }
```

Comment: I almost forgot to mention that i'm getting a very non specific error that i'm not sure how to debug without knowing what the issue is.

Comment: Extremely generic http://localhost:8000/results?Affilation=AFL-CIO&Office_State=&Local_Name=union Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: This error isnt related to eloquent you probably have some wrong configuration in your web server (apache/nginx?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked `app/storage/laravel.log` as well as the nginx and/or php logs on the homestead VM?

Homestead 2 (I'm assuming from the port 8000) uses HHVM by default, so fatal PHP errors and similar don't get shown in the browser.

Just a hunch, but in your post you have `input::get('Local_name')`. There is no such class as `input`, however there is `Input`.

Comment: Casing doesn't matter with PHP classes. `Input::get()` or `iNpUt::get()` does exactly the same. (Although it's not very pretty)

Comment: Learn something new every day :)

Comment: This is the beginning of a long error and what I think is relevant:

Comment: This is the beginning of a long error and what I think is relevant: [2015-02-28 14:20:17] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: unions' in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\storage\views\828b81503d4e5a41a8d04770b175c57d:44
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\storage\views\828b81503d4e5a41a8d04770b175c57d(44): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 44, Array) , This is the line i'm it's referring to: <?php if($unions->count()): ?>
        <?php foreach($unions as $union): ?>

Comment: As the error is saying you have an unidentified variable ($unions) you're trying to use in your view file. In the code in your post you're passing `$union` into the view, not `$unions`